# MVC Kendo Grid Action Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have an Kendo Grid ,first column is hyper link .Each hyper link is binded to a pdf file name.Pdf file will be in project folder.

Grid :

```
  File Name          Date
----------------|--------
     file1.pdf  |12.03.2014
     file2.pdf  |13.03.2014
```

now wen I click this link 'file1.pdf' I want this file name to be passed to the model. Also this Action link should have an action 'GetPdf' which would return PDFResult. Once this link is clicked then the corresponding pdf file should opened in a same page in `<object>` tag. same way if I click second link then file2.pdf should be opened inside object tag with out pagepostback. How to achieve this ?? here is my code.
My View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Myproject.Models.PdffilesModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
columns.Bound(p => p.FileName)
                              .ClientTemplate(
        "<a  href='" +
            @Html.ActionLink("#=FileName#'", "GetPdf", "Home")+
            "/#= FileName #" +
        "</a>" );
 columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate).Width(70);
 })

        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(1))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
                      .ServerOperation(false)

            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Home"))
        )
)
```

HomeController: //here I hard coded the file name but it should come from hyperlink click action

```
public FileStreamResult GetPdf(string filenmae)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("/pdfSample.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(fs, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Datasource to bind the grid:

```
public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetAttachments().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<PdffilesModel>GetAttachments()
        {

            IEnumerable<PdffilesModel> finalresult ;
            List<PdffilesModel> list= new List<PdffilesModel>();
            var northwind = new PdffilesModel();

            northwind.FileName = "file1.pdf";           
            northwind.CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014,03,04).ToString("d");
            list.Add(northwind);           

            finalresult = list;

            return finalresult;
        }
```

This is the object tag should bind with pdf result when grid action link is clicked.

```
<object class="pdfdiv" id="ajaxpdf" data="@Url.Action("GetPdf")"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

*************************Grid***************************

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SearchEmailHistoryGridModel>()
            .Name("EmailSearchGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {

                columns.Bound(p => p.ExtractId).Visible(false);
                columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Title("File Name");
                columns.Bound(p => p.TemplateName).Title("Template");
                columns.Bound(p => p.CentreName).Title("Centre");
                columns.Bound(p => p.LeaseId).Title("Lease ID");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Unit).Title("Unit").Width("80px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Occupant).Title("Occupant");
                columns.Bound(p => p.ContactName).Title("Contact");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Attachment).Title("Attachment").ClientTemplate("# if(data.Attachment!=null) {# <div style='cursor: hand;'><a class='gridLink' href='\\#' id='slpitLink'  title='Download #:Attachment#' onclick=\"DownloadFile(#:ExtractId#,'#:FileName#','#:Attachment#'); return false;\">View</a></div> #}#");
                columns.Bound(p => p.EmailAddress).Title("Email").Width("150px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.EmailSent).Title("Email Sent").Visible(false);
                columns.Bound(p => p.FirstSentDate).Title("Date Sent").Width("85px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.SentBy).Title("Sent By").Width("85px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Delivered).Title("Delivered").Width("85px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Read).Title("Read").Width("70px");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Exception).Title("Error").ClientTemplate("# if(data.Exception=='Yes') {# <a style='color:\\#94BB27; text-decoration:none; cursor:help' title='#:data.ExceptionDescription#'>Yes</a> #} else {# <label>No</label>  #}#").Width("60px");



                columns.Command(command =>
                {
                    command.Custom("Resend").Click("ResendEmail").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Resend Email" });
                    command.Custom("Forward").Click("SendForwardEmail").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Forward Email" });
                }).Title("Action");


            })
            .Events(e => e.DataBound("onEmailSearchDataBound"))
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 20,50 })
                    .ButtonCount(5)
                    )
            .Filterable()                
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:650px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))  
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(c => c.ExtractId);

                    })   
                .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmailHistory", "EmailManagement").Data("GetSearchFilterData")) 

            )

        )
```

*******************************Script***********************************

```
  //Download File
          function DownloadFile(extractId,folder,fileNameParam) {


              $.post('@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Correspondence")', { extractId: extractId, folder: folder, fileName: fileNameParam })
                .done(function (data) {
                    if (data.url == null) {

                        showMessage(data);
                    }
                    else {

                        $("body").append("<iframe src='" + data.url + "' style='display: none;'></iframe>");
                    }

                });

          }
```

**********************************Controller****************************

```
   //Download File
    [HttpPost]
    [FilterSessionExpire]
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(int extractId,string folder, string fileName)
    {

        var filePath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EcorsSplitFilePath"],folder, fileName); //in folder level

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //return file link
            return Json(new { url = Url.Action("DownloadFileActual", "Correspondence", new { folder = folder, fileName = fileName }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //else return error
        return Json("File:" + fileName + " Not found.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


   //Actual Download File 
    public ActionResult DownloadFileActual(string folder, string fileName)
    {
        const string contentType = "application/pdf";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EcorsSplitFilePath"], folder, fileName); //in folder level
        return File(filePath, contentType, fileName);


    }
```